# an unexpected NullPointerException in non-taken branch of ternary?

Tags: java

I have two variables:

```
final Long a;
if(...) {
     a = ...;
} else
     a = null;
String b  = "A";
....
```

and then later, assignment to another `Long` is throwing a `NullPointerException`:

```
final Long c = b.equals("B")? a*1000: a;
```

I am expecting `c` to be `null` if `a` is `null`, and I'm expecting `b`, which I *know* to not be `B` in these circumstances to prevent it being dereferenced.

So why does it throw the `NullPointerException`?

***UPDATE***: mystery solved, its auto-unboxing in the tenary operator. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/13627200/15721

Comment: Perhaps the else clause has worked and a became null so it throws NullPointerException

Comment: When asking for help with a problem with code, it's best to quote the *actual code*. Otherwise, you're likely to hide the problem.

Comment: Please show a short but complete program demonstrating the problem. It will remove a lot of confusion.

Comment: This is reproducible with just `final Long a = null;
  
  String b = "A";
  
  final Long c = b.equals("B") ? a * 1000 : a;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aha, from finding code that works I can infer what is happening:

```
Long a = ....; 
Long b = ... a != null? a*1000: a;
```

Because `a*1000` is unboxing `a`, the tenary expression is `long` not `Long`.

```
Long a = ....; 
Long b = ... a != null? new Long(a*1000): a;
```

Keeps the tenary outcome `Long` and works as expected.

Answer (score 3):

Because if `a` is `null`, as it is a `Long` it will evaluate as `null.longValue()` throwing a `NullPointerException`

**Edit:**

I expect that the ternary operator evaluates to a long since you are doing a multiplication, and then even if it goes on the second branch, `a` is evaluated to a `long` (unboxed)

**Edit2:**
You were faster to finally find your own answer ;)

Comment: but my string value guard is to prevent that, and I know from printf debugging that my string is not `"B"` when `a` is `null` and the exception occurs.

Answer (score 1):

When you do `a * 1000`, `a` is unboxed.

Therefore if `a` is `null`, then `a * 1000` throws a `NullPointerException`!